# c# calculater bearing between two lat and long coords from NMEA log file?

Tags: c#, gps

With the following extract from a GPS log:

```
$GPGGA,153500.009,5137.2603,N,00244.8715,W,1,10,0.8,50.6,M,51.4,M,,0000*71
$GPRMC,153500.009,A,5137.2603,N,00244.8715,W,037.7,101.7,300912,,,A*74
$GPGGA,153500.059,5137.2601,N,00244.8706,W,1,10,0.8,50.6,M,51.4,M,,0000*74
$GPRMC,153500.059,A,5137.2601,N,00244.8706,W,038.0,101.8,300912,,,A*76
$GPGGA,153500.109,5137.2600,N,00244.8697,W,1,10,0.8,50.6,M,51.4,M,,0000*78
$GPRMC,153500.109,A,5137.2600,N,00244.8697,W,038.3,101.9,300912,,,A*78
$GPGGA,153500.159,5137.2599,N,00244.8688,W,1,10,0.8,50.5,M,51.4,M,,0000*73
$GPRMC,153500.159,A,5137.2599,N,00244.8688,W,038.6,101.9,300912,,,A*75
$GPGGA,153500.209,5137.2597,N,00244.8679,W,1,10,0.8,50.5,M,51.4,M,,0000*75
$GPRMC,153500.209,A,5137.2597,N,00244.8679,W,038.9,102.0,300912,,,A*76
```

I am comparing the logged GPS bearing with a calculated bearing between the last and current position with the following code that loops through each line:

```
string[] splitline = line.Split(',');
course = Convert.ToDouble(splitline[8]);
Lat = Convert.ToDouble(splitline[3]);
Long = Convert.ToDouble(splitline[5]);

LatDeg = (Convert.ToInt16(Lat) / 100) + (Lat - (Convert.ToInt16(Lat) / 100) * 100) / 60;
LongDeg = (Convert.ToInt16(Long) / 100) + (Long - (Convert.ToInt16(Long) / 100) * 100) / 60;
lastLatDeg = (Convert.ToInt16(lastLat) / 100) + (lastLat - (Convert.ToInt16(lastLat) / 100) * 100) / 60;
lastLongDeg = (Convert.ToInt16(lastLong) / 100) + (lastLong - (Convert.ToInt16(lastLong) / 100) * 100) / 60;

var dLon = lastLongDeg - LongDeg;
var y = Math.Sin(dLon) * Math.Cos(lastLatDeg);
var x = Math.Cos(lastLatDeg) * Math.Sin(LatDeg) - Math.Sin(lastLatDeg) *           Math.Cos(LatDeg) * Math.Cos(dLon);
Console.WriteLine(DEG_PER_RAD * Math.Atan2(y, x));
Console.WriteLine("> " + course + " <");

lastLat = Lat;
lastLong = Long;
lastcourse = course;
```

results in the following:

```
136.131182151555
> 101.8 <
117.480364881602
> 101.9 <
117.480186101881
> 101.9 <
136.130309531745
> 102 <
117.479649572813
> 102 <
```

are my calculations out as none of them seem to come close to the gps logged bearing of around 101 degrees?

Thanks

Comment: why are you converting to integer.  To get precise number keep results as a double and divide by 100.00.  You can truncate the final results after performing the math using Math.Round.

Comment: only reason is to split the original lat long format: 5137.2597 = 5137 as int then divide that by 100 = 51 ie GPRMC lat long format = 51deg 37.2597mins and this needs to be conerted to decimal deg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems I spotted in the code, for a start when interpreting the latitude and longitude you should look at which quadrant of the earth the positions fall into and convert to negative for south or west locations:

```
Lat = Convert.ToDouble(splitline[3]);
if (splitline[4] == "S")
    Lat = 0.0 - Lat;
Long = Convert.ToDouble(splitline[5]);
if (splitline[6] == "W")
    Long = 0.0 - Long;
```

The remainder of the problems stemmed from passing degrees rather than radians to the math functions and the calculation of the longitude delta seemed reversed. I introduced a few helper functions and rewrote that section of code as follows:

```
public static double DegreesToRadians(double degrees)
{
    return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
}

public static double RadiansToDegrees(double radians)
{
    return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
}

double dLon = DegreesToRadians(LongDeg - lastLongDeg);
double y = Math.Sin(dLon) * Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(lastLatDeg));
double x = Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(lastLatDeg)) * Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(LatDeg)) - Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(lastLatDeg)) * Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(LatDeg)) * Math.Cos(dLon);
Console.WriteLine((RadiansToDegrees(Math.Atan2(y, x)) + 360.0) % 360);
Console.WriteLine("> " + course + " <");
```

That gave me the following results with your test data ignoring the first invalid one where the bearing has not yet been determined:

```
109.693614586392
> 101.8 <
100.14641169874
> 101.9 <
100.146411372034
> 101.9 <
109.693611985053
> 102 <
```

I noticed from the GGA speeds that the unit seems to have been either stationary or moving very slowly. Some GPS receivers will filter or hold heading information under those circumstances so some variation can be expected. After the changes I ran through some GPS data I had from a moving vehicle and the results were within one degree of each other.

Comment: Thanks PeterJ that works as i wanted, i think i need to look at smoothing the data or reading in every 2 as at 10hz the small distance can cause errors eg flipping from 109 to 100 degres in 0.1 seconds makes a wavy line.